# Laravel eloquent orderby relation

Tags: php, laravel

I use eloquent to get data from many tables but I'm don't achieve to order my last table but "ordre" rather than "id".

My setup :

```
$etages_lot = EtageLot::where('lot_id', $lot_id)->with('variantes', 'variantes.piece')->get();
```

EtageLot model :

```
public function lot(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
}

public function etage(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Etage');
}

public function fractions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Fraction','etage_lot_id');
}

public function variantes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Variante', 'lot_variante')->withPivot('nombre');
}
```

Variante model :

```
    public function piece(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Piece')->orderBy('ordre', 'asc');
}

public function EtageLot(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot','lot_variante')->withPivot('nombre');
}
```

Piece model :

```
public function variantes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Variante');
}
```

I get all data but last part, piece, isn't order by ordre asc.

I tried :

```
        $etages_lot = EtageLot::where('lot_id', $lot_id)->with('etage', 'variantes')->with(['variantes.piece' => function ($query)
    {
        $query->orderBy('ordre','asc');
    }])->get();
```

But it doesn't work neither.

An idea why I can't get the last part of my data with another order ?

Thank for your help.

Edit : add some migrations :

etage_lot table :

```
        Schema::create('etage_lot', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('lot_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('etage_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('lot_id')->references('id')->on('lots')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('etage_id')->references('id')->on('etages')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

lot_variante table :

```
        Schema::create('lot_variante', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('etage_lot_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('etage_lot_id')->references('id')->on('etage_lot')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('variante_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('variante_id')->references('id')->on('variantes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('nombre')->unsigned();
        $table->unique(['etage_lot_id', 'variante_id']);
    });
```

variantes table :

```
        Schema::create('variantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom')->default('sans');
        $table->integer('piece_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('piece_id')->references('id')->on('pieces')->onDelete('cascade'); 
        $table->unique(['nom', 'piece_id']);
    });
```

pieces table :

```
        Schema::create('pieces', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom')->unique();
        $table->string('nom_pluriel')->unique();
        $table->integer('ordre')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->string('article');
        $table->tinyInteger('show_article')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('compte_pluriel')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('jouissance')->default(0);

    });
```

Comment: Can we see tables from EtageLot please?

Comment: I added tables migrations !

Comment: Do you want to order `variantes` by `piece.ordre`?

Comment: I don't care if variantes are order, I juste need piece order by ordre

Comment: A `variante` only has one `piece`. How do you want to order that?

Comment: Ok I see, so it must be sort variante by piece.ordre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a modified [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
$etages_lot = EtageLot::where('lot_id', $lot_id)
    ->with(['etage', 'variantes' => function ($query) {
        $query->withCount(['piece as piece_ordre' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('ordre');
        }])->orderBy('piece_ordre')->with('piece');
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this if I split my pieces table into two tables (pieces and jouissances) and use morphMany ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Ordering a query by a `MorphTo` relationship is quite complex because you have to look at different tables depending on the `_type` column.

Comment: Even if these two tables have the same structure ?

Comment: Yes, even then.

Comment: Is there a better way to organize this ? My pieces table contain two types of data and before I ordered my first data from 0 and my second from 100

Comment: Do you want all pieces of type 1 first and then all pieces of type 2?

Comment: Yes order by column 'ordre' in each table.

Comment: Both types have the same column structure, right? Then I would store them in the same table. What column and values are you using to store the type?

Comment: The problem is there are two kind of pieces. Type1 and type2. Type1 are before type2. Both type have order that can be change but type1 are always before type2. Number of type isn't defined.

Comment: Or maybe can I manually get type1 order by ordre and type2 order by ordre ?

Comment: Or (sorry to bother you) can I retrieve variable order by morph order column ? Maybe on the model directly

Comment: Please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $etages_lot = EtageLot::with(['etage', 'variantes.piece'])->where('lot_id', $lot_id);

    $etages_lot->where(function ($query) {
         $query->whereHas('variantes.piece', function ($newquery) {
              $newquery->orderBy('pieces.ordre',"asc")->get()->toArray();
          });          
    });
```

try using this

Comment: I add this error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'variantes.piece_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `pieces` where `variantes`.`piece_id` = `pieces`.`id` order by `pieces`.`ordre` asc)

Comment: $query->whereHas('variantes.piece', function ($newquery) {

IN above line 'variants.piece' replace with only 'piece'.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::piece does not exist. I don't have piece method inside etage_lot

Comment: Ohh sorry my mistake in name 

set $query->whereHas('pieces', function ($newquery) {

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pieces does not exist. Must I add some relation on my models ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` methods to put "where" conditions on your `has` queries. These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment:

```
$etages_lot = EtageLot::where('lot_id', $lot_id)
 ->with('etage', 'variantes')
 ->whereHas('variantes.piece', function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('ordre', 'asc');
 })->get();
```

Comment: I put whereHas after with or must I nested it inside variantes.piece ?